# Find the mean in a normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

A normal distribution has a standard deviation equal to $10$. What is the mean of this normal distribution if the probability of scoring below $x = 10$ is $0.5$?

Answer (score 1):

In a probability distribution, if the probability of scoring below $x = 10$ is exactly $0.5$, then the median $= 10$.
In normal distribution, median $=$ mean, therefore, we can know that mean $= 10$.